# security for Inter communication between microservices in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, jwt, microservices

I am having 12 micro services communicating with each other and  all are built using spring boot. I have one auth service which authenticates  incoming request from a client. But I am not getting how to secure inter communication between microservices?

Comment: do all these microservices are exposed to external world or are these internal services?

Comment: 2 microservices are exposed but they are secured with Authentication using JWT token. Internal microservice how can i secure the communication ?

Comment: check out my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292149/authentication-between-microservices-amazon-api-gateway

If the internal microservices are not exposed to the world, then you do not need any authentication. If you still want to implement some sort of authentication, go for basic auth

Comment: But In my case we have deployed all microservices to AWS EC2 instance and I can  directly access the microservices other than Auth Microservice which is the entry point for any request

Comment: That is fairly simple to change. You can make sure that your ec2 instances are accessible only within your Virtual private Cloud(VPC) and not accessible from outside. Check on that. You can put the 2 microservices accessible form outside in one security group and others in another security group. And you can control the access